# Wired LAN works for 5 min and then stop working

Tags: networking

Internet (wired) works fine in windows but In Ubuntu 12.10 it stop working after 5 min of starting Ubuntu although connection does not disconnect it shows connected even if its not working.

My laptop model is Lenovo Ideapad Z560.

```
sai@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 88:ae:1d:39:88:40  
          inet addr:172.17.3.252  Bcast:172.17.15.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8aae:1dff:fe39:8840/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11179 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:137 errors:0 dropped:47 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:952745 (952.7 KB)  TX bytes:21060 (21.0 KB)
```

Relevant `lscpi -nnk` output:

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:30a1]
        Kernel driver in use: ath9k
        Kernel modules: ath9k
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:392e]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
```

Comment: can you try this command 'ifconfig eth0' in terminal and let us know the output.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please elaborate more on the hardware you have. Even within the same Thinkpad line they have similar but different ethernet controllers built-in. Please post the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(ethernet|network)"` run from a terminal and **edit** your question with this information.

Comment: please reply soon need to work on ubuntu

Comment: @user123878 If you're in a hurry, you'll have to hire an expert. This is a Q&A site, not a one-on-one support website. Also, please format your question properly (did it for you now). The `ifconfig` output shows me `dropped:47` which indicates a failure in either the hardware, wire or low-level drivers. (I have no solution to this other than posting this suggestion as a comment)

Comment: No everything works fine in wondows and also works for intial 5 mins after ubuntu starts but then it doesn't work even if it is showing connection.

Comment: And second thing if i disconnect manually to try to reconnect it manually from top right corner in ubuntu it does not connect after disconnecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try [wicd [image: Install wicd]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wicd) from Synaptic or Software Center, or install it with:

```
sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude install wicd
```

(Or use `apt-get` if you don't have `aptitude`.)

After you install `wicd`, you have to uninstall `network-manager`.

This may improve things substantially--try it and see!

Comment: In my opinion, this is merely a suggestion and should only be used if you have indications that the standard Network Manager is the issue.